# Insert a variable for a label in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I am looking to replace this in my form -

```
<%= f.label :pick, 'Away' %>
```

with something like -

```
<%= f.label :pick, @name %>
```

In my model Teacher I have this -

```
def name
    @name = school.student.name
end
```

Teacher

```
belongs_to :school
```

School

```
belongs_to :student
```

Student has column called name

My response is -

```
Pick
```

I would like the response of the Student Name

Comment: You need to define the `@name` variable in the controller, not your model. For the form, `@name` is `nil` - and thus the helper falls back to the `name` attribute instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @sjagr said, you need to declare the `@name` variable in the controller action that handles the page you are rendering.

Comment: No problem will delete it now!

Answer (score 0):

@sjagr thanks for jogging my brain for the answer, because it was that obvious!

I added this to the controller under the **correct** page (edit) this time -

```
@name = @teacher.name
```

The model stays the same since I need the relationship from the teacher to the student name

```
def name
    @name = school.student.name
end
```

The model allowed the full path I was looking for that would not work in my controller alone

```
teacher.school.student.name
```